# howto debug autoconf failure building alsa-utils 1.1.2 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, autoconf, alsa

A customer of mine still uses Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64 as a software development environment, even though Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64 is available as of this posting.

When configuring the alsa-utils 1.1.2 package the following error happens:

```
checking panel.h usability... yes
checking panel.h presence... yes
checking for panel.h... yes
checking menu.h usability... yes
checking menu.h presence... yes
checking for menu.h... yes
checking form.h usability... yes
checking form.h presence... yes
checking for form.h... yes
checking for new_panel in -lpanel... no
configure: error: panel library not found
```

The same configuration completes successfully on Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64.

What is the best way to debug this error?

The configure command is:

```
configure \
    --target=x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu \
    --host=x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu \
    --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu \
    --prefix=/usr \
    --exec-prefix=/usr \
    --sysconfdir=/etc \
    --localstatedir=/var \
    --program-prefix="" \
    --disable-dependency-tracking \
    --disable-xmlto \
    --with-curses=ncurses \
    --disable-alsaloop \
    --disable-bat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `config.log` file that is generated, it'll show how the build command that tried to make a test program link with `libpanel` failed.

Answer (score 0):

Configure Alsautils doesnt output fully log error,
maybe you are missing libtinfo.so in build ncurses. Rebuild **ncurses** with options `--with-libtic --with-libterm` and check presence `/usr/lib/libtinfo.so` And after try again build alsautils with option `--disable-nls` to dont get the same error with `libpanelw.so` (`w_char` panel) or build ncurses with support wide-characters(`--enable-widec`).

Also see build ncurses in LFS http://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter06/ncurses.html